# What is the best way to use MySQL on Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku

I'm about to move an app to Heroku and need to run a MySQL DB. What's the best way to do this? I don't find many happy people using ClearDB, but maybe it's the best one? Maybe the best option is to keep it outside heroku? Fiddling in the dark here and bit of a noob when it comes to cloud.
Maybe I need to migrate to Postgres?

Comment: Yes, it's a lot of maybes. How would we know?

Comment: Maybe it's not the right place for that kind of question...

Comment: This was my first question on SO. Will try to make it more clear next time. I was hoping someone who moved a mySQL db to Heroku could advice me on how to approach it best.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear answer in Heroku docs about using MySQL in Heroku which says use ClearDB:

> ClearDB is a powerful, fault tolerant database-as-a-service in the cloud for your MySQL powered applications.

[devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb)

And you are asking an opinion based question, which is not for SO.

In your case I would ask unhappy people why they are unhappy with ClearDB, and compare their answers with your needs.

Comment: It was really no my intention to ask for opinions on it. I was just asking for alternatives. Documentation is sometimes out dated so I was asking for advice. Thanks for your quick answer. I guess I need to look elsewhere for some other option than using ClearDB then. Let me know if you have other ideas.